# Excel formula to determine the number of months per annual slice from period

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula with which I can determine how many months from a certain period are allocated to the affected years of the period.

Example:
**Start date:** `11/01/2023`
**End date:** `03/31/2025`

The formula should now output in a table that `2` months fall on `2023`, `12` months on `2024`, `3` months on `2025` and `0` month on `2026`.

I Hope you got it.
Looking forward to any help

I tried with several if conditions.
Like if start date smaller then year1, than „0“ etc.

Answer (score 1):

We could also take advantage of EDATE:

````
=LET(m,YEAR(EDATE(B1,SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(B1,B2,"m")+1,,0))),
     u,UNIQUE(m),
HSTACK(u,MMULT(N(TOROW(m)=u),m^0)))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula, not sure why you need the year `2026` however, using <kbd>MMULT()</kbd> this can be accomplished:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, B1,
     φ, B2,
     δ, DATE(YEAR(α),SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(α,φ,"M")+1,,MONTH(α),1),1),
     Ψ, YEAR(δ),
     VSTACK({"Year","Counts"},UNIQUE(HSTACK(Ψ,MMULT(N(Ψ=TOROW(Ψ)),Ψ^0)))))
```

---

Another way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, SEQUENCE(B2-B1+1,,B1),
     φ, RIGHT(UNIQUE(TEXT(α,"mmm-yyyy")),4),
     VSTACK({"Year","Counts"},
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(φ,MMULT(N(φ=TOROW(φ)),φ^0)))))
```

---

If the `Year 2026` is needed then,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TEXT(SEQUENCE(EDATE($B$2,12)-$B$1,,$B$1),"mmm-yyyy"),
     φ, TEXT(SEQUENCE($B$2-$B$1+1,,$B$1),"mmm-yyyy"),
     δ, RIGHT(UNIQUE(FILTER(α,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(α,φ)))),4),
     Ψ, UNIQUE(RIGHT(α,4)),
     HSTACK(Ψ,MMULT(N(Ψ=TOROW(δ)),δ^0)))
```

---